# Adding the number to the according index it is positioned in

Tags: ruby

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.map.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    if row > 9
      row.to_s.reverse.chop.to_i
    else 
      index + row
    end
  end
end
```

Hi,

I have a method which adds the number to the according index it is positioned in. However I have two rules:

1. The index starts at (1)
2. If the number is a multiple, remove the first integer off the end of it. 12 would become 2 for example.

The problem is I am unsure how to include an 'if' statement inside a block and I believe I am doing it wrong. I know there is a much better way to write this statement but I am finding it hard.

Example:

```
incrementer([4,6,9,1,3]) => [5,8,2,5,8]

  - 9 + 3 (position of 9 in array) = 12 
  - Only its last digit 2 should be returned
```

Comment: Please provide a simple example, including the desired result. Where you say, "remove the last integer" do you mean "remove the last diigt"?

Comment: Do you want to remove the last digit *and* increment it, or just remove the last digit? EG should [3, 2, 4, 10] become [4, 4, 7, 1] or [4, 4, 7, 2] ?

Comment: Have updated for all.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: Have updated my answer (as have others), so you may want to take a look:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fixing your code

Use `map` followed by `with_index(1)`, the argument offsetting the initial index by `+1`.

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.map.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    row = index + row
    if row > 9
      row.digits.first
    else 
      row
    end
  end
end

incrementer [3, 2, 4, 10]  #=> [4, 4, 7, 4]
incrementer [4, 6, 9, 1, 3] #=> [5, 8, 2, 5, 8]
```

---

#### Negative numbers

Numbers can be negative and for which we can use `abs.digits` but it may be better to use `Integer#remainder`.

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.map.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    row = index + row
    case row
    when -9..9
      row
    else 
      row.remainder 10
    end
  end
end

incrementer [3, 2, 4, 10]
 #=> [4, 4, 7, 4]
incrementer [4, 6, 9, 1, 3]
 #=> [5, 8, 2, 5,8]
incrementer [3, 2, 4,-17]
 #=> [4, 4, 7, -3]
incrementer [4, 6, -22, 1, 3]
 #=> [5, 8, -9, 5, 8]
```

**Why not use `%` instead of `Integer#remainder`?**

`a % b` returns `a modulo b` which is not the same thing as the remainder. This has consequences for negative numbers:

```
-12 % 10 #=> 8 not the last digit
```

So we need to use `Integer#remainder`, so:

```
-12.remainder 10 #=> -2
```

Which is what we need, i.e. the last digit (parity included). It can be noted in other languages such as JavaScript, `a % b` returns the remainder.

As noted by @moveson the above code can be refactored to:

```
num.map.with_index(1) { |row, index| (index + row).remainder 10 }
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the answer

Comment: The conditional is unnecessary. `row.remainder 10` will return the expected value in all conditions. Lines 3 through 10 can be reduced to `(index + row).remainder 10`

Answer (score 3):

The `#digits` method requires Rails or ActiveSupport (or Ruby 2.4+), and it's not necessary. Here is a pure Ruby solution that works with any Ruby version:

```
def incrementer(array)
  array.map.with_index(1) { |integer, index| (integer + index) % 10 }
end
```

This code above says: For each element of the array, add its index (starting from 1), divide the sum by 10, and return the remainder.

The `%` (modulo) operator divides the number before it by the number after it and returns the remainder. For example, `22 % 7` returns `1`. It's an extremely useful tool and can often help avoid the use of conditionals entirely, such as in your example. Using `%`, you can get the last digit of a number `n` (whether or not `n` is greater than 9) by simply taking `n % 10`.

Now you can do:

```
>> incrementer([3,2,4,10])
=> [4, 4, 7, 4]
>> incrementer([4,6,9,1,3])
=> [5, 8, 2, 5, 8]
```

Comment: [`Integer#digits`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-digits) :)

Comment: Fair comment--I am using Ruby 2.3 so it did not work in my implementation. But why not just use `%` in any case and avoid the conditional?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two separate problems. The first problem is your use of `each_with_index`. Ruby functions return the value of the last expression they execute, so if you look at your function:

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.each_with_index do |row, index|
    # do some stuff
  end
end
```

It essentially calls `each_with_index` and returns the value. The issue here is that `each_with_index` iterates over an array and then *returns the original array*. What you want to do is change each item in the array and return a new array with the new values. For this, you can use map:

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.map.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    # do some stuff
  end
end
```

In this case, you can even conveniently pass in the parameter `1` to tell the iterator to start at index 1.

Now the second problem is that your if-else-statement either iterates a number or wraps it around. But what you actually want to do is iterate a number *and* wrap it around if it's bigger than 9. You can do that like so:

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.map.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    row = index + row
    if row > 9
      row.to_s.reverse.chop.to_i
    else 
      row
    end
  end
end
```

What we're doing here is iterating the number *first*, saving it into `row` and *then* checking to see if it's over 9. If it is, we return the last digit; otherwise, we just return the value `row`.

This code will do what you want, but let's make one more change for the sake of clarity. This code:

```
row.to_s.reverse.chop.to_i
```

Is a little bit confusing. Ruby 2.4 has a convenient method for getting at the digits of an integer:

```
row.digits.first
```

This is easy to read, but it's a bit slow since it turns an integer into an array of integers. A better way is to use modulus `%` to get the remainder of your number, divided by 10. This is fast and easy to read for most programmers, since it's a common trick.

```
row % 10
```

Putting it all together, you get:

```
def incrementer(num)
  num.map.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    row = index + row
    if row > 9
      row % 10
    else 
      row
    end
  end
end
```

Special thanks to (@sagarpandya84) and (@moveson) for allowing me to build on their answers.

Comment: @moveson The only thing my answer adds is an explanation, but considering that the question asker originally asked how to use if-statements inside blocks, I thought an explanation would be helpful to them.

Comment: To be fair, I started this answer before sagarpandya84 posted theirs. While I updated it after seeing value in other posted answers, I never set out to copy an already existing answer. Still, I can add attribution if you like.